# Number of certificates can be created for a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Hi I am planning to use AWS IOT for my project which will have many devices and for each device we need to create certificate. On AWS IOT site, It is written that you can add countless number of devices.But I need to know that is there any limitation on generating certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on the number of devices, certificates or policies you can have.